# Jquery and PHP hierarchy view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, hierarchy, web-frontend

Good day!

Can you help me construct a jquery function to output the below array to the view similar to this link [CSS Hierarchy Struture](https://medium.com/@sichisichi/hierarchy-view-component-with-pure-css-sass-1ff5add5cad7#.5b88ibknd)?

the structure "contains one parent element with N number of child elements. The component HTML structure is composed of two block: .hv-item-parent and .hv-item-children -wrapper for children"

[structure in css - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8F7Z.png)

In not really good at frontend dev. 
Thank you in advance!

PHP Script:

```
public function buildStructure($details=array(), $parentId = 0) {
  $build = array();
  foreach ($details as $dtl) {
      if ($dtl['parent_job_int_id'] == $parentId) {
          $children = $this->buildStructure($details, $dtl['child_job_int_id']);
          if ($children) 
              $dtl['children'] = $children;              
          $build[] = $dtl;
      }
  }
  return $build;
}
```

Output in Array:

```
Array
(
    [child_id] => 6
    [parent_id] => 0
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [child_id] => 7
                    [parent_id] => 6
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [child_id] => 18
                                    [parent_id] => 7
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [child_id] => 11
                    [parent_id] => 6
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [child_id] => 40
                                    [parent_id] => 11
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [child_id] => 73
                                                    [parent_id] => 40
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [child_id] => 83
                                                    [parent_id] => 40
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [child_id] => 20
                                                                    [parent_id] => 83
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [child_id] => 49
                                    [parent_id] => 11
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [child_id] => 26
    [parent_id] => 0
)
```

Create loop for array output (view same as the link)
??

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? This sounds like homework. [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I tried few times in jQuery with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the orgchart to get the hierarchy chart here is the link
https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart